# Identical Docker images with different containers and ports not accessible

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm running Docker host on my Windows dev machine and have 2 identifcal images exposing different ports (3000, 3001). Using the following docker-compose I build and run the containers but the container on port 3001 isn't available via localhost or my IP address.

DockerFile

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:8

# Create an app directory (in the Docker container)
RUN mkdir -p /testdirectory
WORKDIR /testdirectory

COPY package.json /testdirectory
RUN npm install --loglevel=warn
COPY . /testdirectory

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

DockerFile

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:8

# Create an app directory (in the Docker container)
RUN mkdir -p /test2directory
WORKDIR /test2directory

COPY package.json /test2directory
RUN npm install --loglevel=warn
COPY . /test2directory

EXPOSE 3001
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

Docker-Compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
    testdirectory:
      container_name: testdirectory
      environment:
      - DEBUG=1
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - NODE_NAME=testdirectory
      - NODE_HOST=localhost
      - NODE_PORT=3000
      - DB_HOST=mongodb://mongo:27017/testdirectory
      - DB_PORT=27017
      build:
        context: ./test-directory
      volumes:
        - .:/usr/app/
        - /usr/app/node_modules
      ports:
        - "3000:3000"
      depends_on:
        - mongodb
      command: npm start
    test2directory:
      container_name: test2directory
      environment:
      - DEBUG=1
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - NODE_NAME=test2directory
      - NODE_HOST=localhost
      - NODE_PORT=3001
      - DB_HOST=mongodb://mongo:27017/test2directory
      - DB_PORT=27017
      build:
        context: ./test2-directory
      volumes:
        - .:/usr/app/
        - /usr/app/node_modules
      ports:
        - "3001:3001"
      depends_on:
        - mongodb
      command: npm start      
    mongodb:
      image: mongo:3.4.4
      container_name: mongo
      ports:
        - 27017:27017
      volumes: 
        - /data/db:/data/db
```

Is there any obvious I'm missing as when I run

```
docker container port test2directory
```

it returns

```
3001/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:3001
```

Comment: Does your application (index.js) listening on port 3001?

Comment: yes the second container runs on 3001 and when I run it locally outside the container it's available on localhost:3001. I'm happy to put them both on 3000 internally and have the external port mapped to 3001 for one and 3000 for the other but thought it should be easy to have them both different  (for localised testing)

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem! Setting the HOST to localhost in the container caused the problem and changing it to 0.0.0.0 got it working.